# Display TextView containing information from the database

Tags: android, database, textview

How can I display a `TextView` containig information from the data base ?
My application displays this information as a `Toast` but I need it in a TextView.

```
displayTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);       
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected.getAdresse(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: displayTextView.setText(selected.getAdresse());

Comment: Try to explore..There are lots of answers available, atleast provide what you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Textview.settext](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

```
displayTextView.settext(selected.getAdresse().toString());
```

Comment: I cannt because it is a new account I have nt the permission, I am sorry but I accept it, all your answer was very useful and complete

Answer (score 0):

```
displayTextView.setText(selected.getAdresse());
```

See `setText()` for more info on developer site.

Answer (score 0):

You mean `displayTextView.setText(selected.getAdresse());` ?